# Loading data table view from server hangs it

Tags: uitableview

I'm using below code to fill table view with data and it is also get filled but the problem is that on scrolling table view it get hangs and after taking sometime it get scrolled for a short distance.
The .h file is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JSON.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *homeProfileTableview;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) UIImageView *clockImage;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *ItemImage;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *locationImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *Tableata;

@end
```

The .m file

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import "SBJsonParser.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController
@synthesize homeProfileTableview,clockImage,Tableata,ItemImage,locationImage;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-BoldItalic" size:25.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [buttonView addSubview:button];
    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView];
    [self.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:backItem];


//    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
//                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://izisstechnology.com/garage/index.php?method=login&username=ashu&password=1234"]
//                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
//                            error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://izisstechnology.com/garage/index.php?method=home&start=0"]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                            error:nil];

    SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *results=[parser objectWithString:jsonString ];

    //NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    //[parser release], parser = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",results);
    // Set tableData
    [self setTableata:[results objectForKey:@"new"]];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)refreshButtonTapped {

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [Tableata count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homeProfileTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    NSDictionary *item = [Tableata objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"seller_image"]];


    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];


    //clock image
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(240,10, 20, 20);
    self.clockImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];    
    self.clockImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.jpg"];    
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.clockImage];


    //location image
    CGRect imageFrame1 = CGRectMake(80,20, 20, 20);
    self.locationImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame1];
    self.locationImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.jpg"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.locationImage];


    //username
    UILabel *username=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,0, 70, 20)];
    username.text=[item objectForKey:@"seller_name"];
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"futura" size: 18.0 ];
    username.font  = myFont;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:username];

    //user location
    UILabel *userlocation=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,20, 70, 20)];
    userlocation.text=[item objectForKey:@"prod_country"];
    UIFont *myFont2 = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"futura" size: 18.0 ];
    userlocation.font  = myFont2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:userlocation];

    //item image
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"item_image1"]];


    NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];
    CGRect imageFrame2 = CGRectMake(20,40, 280, 320);
    self.ItemImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame2] ;

    self.ItemImage.image = image1;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.ItemImage];



    UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 30, 30);
    [playButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = image;
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playButton];
    return cell;


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 380;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setNavigationBar:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[CameraViewController class]]) {
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Choose Source Type?"
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Select From Library", @"Capture From Camera", nil];
        [actionSheet showFromTabBar:tabBarController.tabBar];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {
            CameraViewController *cameraViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
            if (!cameraViewController.imagePicker) {
                cameraViewController.imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                cameraViewController.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
            }
            cameraViewController.imagePicker.delegate=self;
            cameraViewController.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentViewController:cameraViewController.imagePicker
                               animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            CameraViewController *cameraViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
            if (!cameraViewController.imagePicker) {
                cameraViewController.imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                cameraViewController.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
            }
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
            {
                cameraViewController.imagePicker.delegate=self;
                cameraViewController.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentViewController:cameraViewController.imagePicker
                                   animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }
            break;
        case 2:
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
-(void)imagePickerController:
(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    CameraViewController *cameraViewController=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    cameraViewController.imageSelected=nil;
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    cameraViewController.imageSelected=image;
    cameraViewController.imagePicker.delegate=cameraViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=cameraViewController;
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:
(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is full of synchronous request. For example:

```
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://izisstechnology.com/garage/index.php?method=home&start=0"]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                            error:nil];
```

or

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

When you do synchronous request, the whole UI gets blocked, because the request are performed on the main thread. Basically most things of UIKit are done on the main thread, for example handling touches, drawing the UI etc. So touches for instance don't get handled until all the data has been downloaded. As a result your app gets buggy.

I recently watched a session of the WWDC 2012 called "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS". It's quite interesting and helpful. Illustrations in the keynote make it easy to understand the materia. Anyway, there a tons of resource on that topic, you just have to google "Asynchronous iOS" and you will find very helpful tutorials etc.